# Bevel problem with edges

Tags: bevel

I have a problem with the Bevel tool.

I would like to make Bevels like in this video-clip:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJutTa9D5a4&t=17s

at <kbd>0:32</kbd>, but I always ending like it is in the screenshhot ...

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I think in the tutorial the extruded plane is not connected to the parallel plane a little bit lower. You can see it being separated (P key) around 17th second.

Answer (score 1):

The video did rush over that segment and did a poor job explaining what he's doing, not even mentioning the Shrink/Fatten operation.

First, make loop cuts. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

Then bevel. Make sure to use only 2 segments. You can either use the scroll wheel or press <kbd>S</kbd> then enter 2. Press <kbd>A</kbd> if you want to go back to resizing the bevel.

[image]

Then loop select all the center loops by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd> holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select more than one.

With the loop cuts selected, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to Shrink/Fatten, this is different to the normal scale because this scales along the normals of faces/edges/vertices rather than scaling relative to the Transform Pivot Point.

[image]